# The event $scope.$on('$destroy') doesn't work updating ionic & angular

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I use $interval and need to detect when the controller is destroyed. Until now, **I have used the $destroy event and it worked perfectly**. For example with this basic code, it prints  *"destroy"* in the console when I go to another page (with a simple `<a href="#/myNewUrl">` in myView.html).

```
angular.module('myModule').controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        console.log('destroy');
    });

}]);
```

But **since I updated Ionic to the new version** (v1.0.0-beta.14), that uses the new version to Angular too (v1.3.6), **the $destroy event isn't detect** when I go to another page.

Does anybody get the same problem? How can I be resolve it?
Thank you for your answer!

---

**EDIT**:

I have finally fixed the problem!!! Now, with the new Ionic version, **the view is cached automatically**. Adding `cache-view="false"` in the template disable it.

But I found a **best way than the destroy event**. Ionic added new events (on **$ionicView**) and now you can detect when you leave the page (and the page stays cached) with: `$ionicView.leave`.

To get more information: http://ionicframework.com/docs/nightly/api/directive/ionView/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Is your template cached? If you don't have `cache: false` in your state routes, then the controller is not destroyed.

Comment: It wasn't in the state routes but the problem was for the cache, thanks for the help!! I don't find anything on the options in the state routes but adding `cache-view="false"` in the ion-view, it works.

Answer (score -3):

http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-destroy-controllers-in-ion-tab-directive/16658

It's a hello from Ionic dev team. They like to leak memory, you see.

Just set

`$ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);`

That should do it

Comment: What an opinionated comment. The case has been covered : http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/ . You can detect when the cached view is leaving, and act accordingly, as the asker precised.

Comment: Please stick to neutral factual advice, and back up with evidence. `"It's a hello from Ionic dev team. They like to leak memory, you see."` sounds more like a rude opinion. Your link says nothing to confirm they like to leak memory.